# Cant airdrop solana token

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

[image]

Noob question:

I get this error when trying to run an anchor test as well,
NOTE: Im on m1 chip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run `solana-test-validator` in a separate terminal before running `solana airdrop`

If you'd like to switch to devnet, run `solana config set --url devnet` or `solana config set -u d`. Note on devnet you can only request to airdrop 2 sol at a time.

If at any time you'd like to check what cluster you're on, run `solana config get`

Comment: Thank you, devnet works, but testnet doesn't work for some reason

Comment: I think testnet is generally used by validators, so airdropping might be disabled?
https://docs.solana.com/clusters#testnet